# Cannot find symbol errors when migrating to Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am having configuration class which contains some property related variable

```
@Data
class Configuration{
String id;
String name; }
```

, on this class I am using @Data annotation for getter setter which is coming from Lombok. It is working fine on spring boot 2.7, but as soon as I updated it, it started showing cannot find id and name symbol error. However I am using latest version of lambok.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have find a fix, I just given Lombok version 1.18.28 in gradle properties **compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'** and it started working, do not know it is a bug or what because it is not working with any other version of Lombok.